# Segmentation Fault w/ character arrays & pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to debug this and figure out what may be causing the segmentation fault. I'm pretty new. This is a small method that  is supposed to remove duplicates that are consecutive within an array.

```
 void removeddup(char *str){
  int i;
  int j;
  int len= str_len(str)-1;
  int removed = 0;
  for(i=0; i < (len-removed);)
    {
      if(str[i]==str[i+1])
        {
          for(j=i; i<(len-removed);j++)
            str[j]=str[j+1];
          removed++;
        }else{
        i++;
      }
    }
}
```

It is called like this

```
char str1[100]
case '6':
      removeddup(str1);
      break;
```

Comment: `for(j=i; i<(len-removed);j++)` : Since `i<(len-removed)` does not change, it may cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `else { i++; }`

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: @Barmar I talk about for-loop.

Comment: My guess is you called the function with a string literal. They can't be modified.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You don't have to change the variable in the `for()` header, you can change it in the body like that as well.

Comment: What's `str1`? How is it declared andf initialized?

Comment: @Barmar What are you talking about?

Comment: What is `str_len` function? What does it do? I still don't see how you initialize your char array.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You should make your comment an answer so OP sees it.

Comment: @Barmar Are you talking about the other loop?

Comment: The inner loop is infinite since it only tests the value of `i`, keeps incrementing `j`, and accesses both `str[j]` and `str[j+1]`.  That means it accesses memory it shouldn't.   Change the test of `i` to a test of `j`.   [Won't necessarily fix all the problems in your code, but will address the segmentation fault].

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Hey, if you were to post this as a solution. I'll be sure to mark it as answered thanks for your help!

Comment: Not enough code is given for the behavior.

Comment: This is basically just a typo, let's close it as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is not bad, one problem is here

```
for(j=i; i<(len-removed);j++)
    str[j]=str[j+1];
```

You keep incrementing `j` but the condition `i<(len-removed)` will hold true
forever. At some point you try to read and write into memory well beyond
boundaries of your memory and you will end up with a `segfault` (like Peter
said). Your problem is that don't calculate correctly how many dupplicate
characters there are.

Let's say you do that

```
str[j]=str[j+1];
```

is also not very efficient. I get the point, you try to copy in `str[j]` the
next character until you find `\0`. Let's say your input is `abccccddddeee`,
that's an awful long number of single copies that you are going to do.

It would be best to calculate the number of duplicate copies and then use
`memmove` to move whole block of memory at once, which is more efficient.

I modified you code using `memmove` instead of your approach. I also left
comments explaining how to calculate the length of the duplicates and the
parameters of `memmove`, that can be hard sometimes. I usually take a piece of
paper and do it by hand first, then you get idea much quicker.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeddup(char *str){
    int i;
    int j;
    int len= strlen(str)-1;
    int removed = 0;

    for(i=0; i < (len-removed);)
    {
        if(str[i]==str[i+1])
        {
            // we calculate the length of the duplicates
            j = 0;
            while(str[i] == str[i + ++j]);

            // we have j duplicates of str[i] (counting str[i])
            // we copy the rest of the string after the j-1 duplicates
            // the destination is the next character after str[i] (str + i +1)
            // the source is str[i+j]
            //
            // now we have to determine how many chars to copy. In general
            // you do string_length - index_of_source + 1, which also copies
            // the \0 string-terminating character.
            //
            // In your case
            //   string_length: len - removed + 1 (the +1 because you 
            //                  defined len := strlen(str)-1;
            //   index_of_source: i + j 
            // ==> len - removed + 1 - (i + j) + 1
            // so

            memmove(str + i + 1, str + i + j, len - removed + 1 - (i+j) + 1);

            // now we set how many characters we've removed
            removed += j - 1;

            // we go the next character
            i++;

        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{

    char text[] = "abccccccdeeefffffffffffff";

    printf("Original: %s\n", text);
    removeddup(text);
    printf("removed:  %s\n", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that this method only works when you have write access to the
buffer. If you pass it a string literal (`const char *text = "abcdddd";`),
you'll get a `segfault` because string literals are in read-only memory.

Also note that the line with the `while` ends with `;`

```
while(condition);

// is equivalent to

while(condition)
{
}
```